# Where is SP progress stored

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

Is my Single Player progress stored on the server or do I need to backup a specific folder when trying to play the game from a different setup ?

Comment: I definitely never needed to back-up my progress. It was just automatically saved to the cloud. Not sure if that's a Uplay setting or not though.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall the file is stored locally in this directory.

```
Uplay\savegames\<your-guid>\2970 or My Documents/My Games/Ghost Recon
```